# Silverlight Entity Framework don’t load Model when I click on .EDMX file in Solution Exporer?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am trying to load data in to datagrid of SilverLight using **Entity Framework** and **WCF Service.**
For that I have followed the article overe here http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2009/07/01/a-simple-silverlight-crud-application--part-1-putting-the.aspx

1. But problem Is when I have added  .edmx file and click on the  “Model.edmx” in solution explorer it doesn’t shows me model but instead of that it shows me message as per below image.
   [image]
2. And in **Mapping Detail** window shows me the message as per below image…instead of Mappings of my database table field and class.
   [image]

Thank You so much........

Comment: make sure you have got tables in the database you selected for Entity framework model...if yes, open you EDMX and right click on it , choose "Update model from database", and see whether it shows you tables in the popup window...

Comment: ya i have table in database...i have created and inserted data in it .....and also i have select that table which i have created in database when i adding .EDMX file

Comment: ok, then check whether tables you have created has primary key or not, because without creating PK for table, EDMX might not work

Comment: oh....thats may be the problem.....i just checking it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check whether tables you have created has primary key or not, because without creating PK for table, EDMX might not show tables model or mapping...**